# How to edit field of foreignkey in admin page?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I have a model which has as an attribute a foreignkey to another model. I would like to edit an attribute on the forienkey'd model from the same admin page as other attributes. I'm struggling with syntax -- it's simply not being changed. Currently my model looks like

```
class MyModel(models.model):
    fk = models.Foreignkey(OtherModel)
    other_attribute = CharField(...)


class OtherModel(models.model):
    field_i_want_to_edit  = BooleanField(default=False)
```

and the form is:

```
class MyModelAdminForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.MyModel
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyModelAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['other_attribute'].label = "Edit this one"

    REC_CHOICES = [
           ('Choice1', 'Remove All things'),
           ('Choice2', 'Add some things'),
    ]

    FLAGGED_CHOICES = [
        (True, 'Flag This One'),
        (False, 'Remove Flag'),
    ]

    edited_recommendation = ChoiceField(choices=REC_CHOICES)
    fk__field__i_want_to_edit = ChoiceField(choices=FLAGGED_CHOICES)
```

But when I choose the entry I want on the admin page for the `field_i_want_to_edit` it doesn't change. Any ideas?

Comment: Django admin isn't set up to edit related models via a parent unless you're using inlines or a custom view.

Comment: Do you have a reference/example of how to do something like this?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects